# Use JQuery setDate and show the date in text box on click of calender icon

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a date dropDown, a month and year inputText in jsf form.I can get these values
and prepare a full date in javascript. Also I have jquery calender implemented as an calender icon,and doesn't open on textBox focus. Now i want that if all values are filled in form and I click on calender, it should open that date accordingly.

```
$('#' + inputid).datepicker({ showOn: ' ',
                             dateFormat : 'M dd yy' ,
                             changeMonth: true ,
                             yearRange: "-90:+10" ,
                             changeYear: true ,
                             duration : "fast" ,
                             showAnim : ""});
```

Request to please provide the setDate function to fit in above code.

Comment: What have you tried?  Provide some sample html . Not clear what fields you are using and how they relate to each other in DOM

Comment: Just simply suppose i have a String value in session as "01/01/2013". Now if I click on Calender, I want my calender to open and show this date. I hope it's clear. In other words how to use setDate here to set date to "01/01/2013"

Comment: still not clear what issue is. Obviously you know how to use `setDate` which is detailed in API, so what is the problem exactly

Comment: problem is solved. Thanks for showing your concern :)